# Regex not working in Javascript with IE 7

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, replace

```
last_tag="abcde   x";
last_tag = last_tag.replace(/[\s]+x$/, '');
```

this is my problem: i have to remove an "x" at the end of my string. This piece of code is used in a plugin i've been using without problems until now. On IE 7 "last_tag" is selected in the wrong way, so i get an "x" and i have to remove it. I think who wrote the plugin added this replace to do exactly this but it's not working on IE7.

Example: 
before:last_tag="abcde   x" 
after: last_tag="abcde"

Actually the problem is that last_tag remain exactly the same.

is the regex correct? is there any error or compatibility issue with IE?

EDIT: Probably the regex is not the issue.

I've tried this piece of code, but nothing happens:

```
var temp_tag="abc x";
alert(temp_tag);
temp_tag = temp_tag.replace(/[\s]+x$/, '');
alert(temp_tag)
```

The same piece of code work perfectly on Chrome.

Comment: The regex is correct and i tested it in IE7 - it's working; Did you test the same replace on other browsers? And are the two lines you've provided an exact copy of the code?

Comment: no but actually i print an alert just before and just after the "replace" and nothing happens, probably the regex is not the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's why i was asking you, if everything else is ok, the only reason this regex won't be working is - different encodings of the "x" letter in the regex and the "x" letter in your subject string. But i suppose you just have a js error somewhere before that

Comment: But just before and just after that, everything works as it does on Chrome.

Comment: So this last piece of code - what happens in IE7 - both alerts give you the same value or there are no alerts?

Comment: Same value, i thought that was obvious. "abc x" the first, "abc x", the second. On chrome, "abc x" the first, "abc" the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex looks okay, but it's possible you're trying to match **non-breaking** spaces (`U+00A0`).  `\s` doesn't match those in IE (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073637/javascript-regex-whitespace-characters/6073721#6073721)), but it does in FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: @AlanMoore then FF and Chrome do it wrong regarding the standards and IE does it right?

Comment: @HerrSerker:  No, it looks like IE is doing it wrong.  The [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ecma-st/ECMA-262.pdf) (section 15.10.2.12) calls for `\s` to include everything in the Unicode `Zs` ('Separator, Space') category, which includes `U+00A0`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for this RegExp

```
/\s+x$/
```

don't use character class `[]` for `\s` which is a character class already
(shorthand for something like `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`) (space, tab, carriage return, line feed, vertical tab, form feed)

---

edit
Alan Moore is right:
try this instead

```
/[\s\u00A0]+x$/
```

---

edit
maybe this is case sensitive: maybe `\u00a0`would not be correct

this should match every white-space-character as well as the non breaking spaces

Comment: I'd go for that regex too, but I wouldn't expect it to solve the problem.  `\s` means the same thing inside a character class as it does outside.

Comment: Perhaps to be even more error safe `[\s\xA0\u00A0\u2028\u2029]`

Comment: ...or `[\s\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u20A0\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]`, which is equivalent to `[\t\n\v\f\r\p{Z}\uFEFF]` in flavors that support Unicode property escapes.  Yes, that last one is the BOM character; don't ask me why ECMAScript tossed that one in.

Comment: @AlanMoore I thought that \uFEFF is the **ZERO WIDTH NON BREAKING SPACE** (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)

Comment: Well, it was both, but that caused too much confusion, so they made it the BOM full-time and gave its other job (whatever that is) to `U+2060`.  Of course, decoders are supposed to *remove* the BOM, but that doesn't always happen.  In those cases, treating it as whitespace makes as much sense as anything, I suppose.

Comment: @AlanMoore I see. I did a little research. What first was the replacement for U+FEFF (ZWNBSP not BOM) was U+2060 (WORD JOINER), which is deprecated now and itself somewhat replaced by U+200D (ZERO WIDTH JOINER), which I thought before is only for arabic letters (as well as ZWNJ U+200C). see here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/01/20/357028.aspx (And now the discussion is beginning to get academic :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
last_tag = last_tag.replace(/[\t\r\n]+x$/, '');
```

Comment: \s includes all \t, \r and \n